# Script Shell Find a String in a file

Tags: ubuntu, script

Here is the structure of my file:

```
/**** Some Text here ****/                         
UN  10.147.243.93  51.46 KB   256     34.2%
UN  10.147.243.89  83.05 KB   256     34.6%
DN  10.147.243.88  66.43 KB   256     32.7%
```

Here is my script

```
file=$1
echo $file
if grep -q DN $File; then
   echo "Get the corresponding IP address, It is the treatment that I   
         want to do next"
fi
```

But, it diplay just the file name.
Have you an idea please ?

2- I'd like then, to extract the corresponding IP address. Here is some details:

```
if grep -q DN $File; then
   echo "Get the corresponding IP address Guest, It is the treatment 
   that I want to do next"
   variable=This address


fi
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Best Regards.

Comment: why don't you use `-f` to specify the filename? Also - please specify the shell that you are using. "Script" is not enough since there are quite important differences between sh, bash, csh and so on.

Comment: if grep -q DN -f $File; then   ---> it display "grep --help"

Comment: You have a typo: "$File" versus "$file"

Comment: if it is displaying `grep --help` it means the syntax used is incorrect. I suggest to move the condition that you used in `if` and test it in the interactive shell - see why it is not working.

Comment: i have to change "$File" to "$file" if grep -q DN $file; then  --> it display the message, thank you so much. Please, is it possible to extract the corresponding IP address.

Comment: @researcher update your question if you want to extract part of the file, as it depends what you want to do with it: print it, store it in a variable, use it in another command etc

Comment: question updated, i'd like to store it in a variable. Thank you so much for help. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, you should correct the `$File` typo.

Depending on what you do with the output, you may not need the `if` test at all. You say you would like the IP address stored in a variable:

```
file=$1
echo $file
ip=$(grep -e DN $1 | awk '{ print $2; }')
echo $ip
```

This can be simplified a lot further for what it's worth, but it matches what you have already.

Note that this will only match the **first** instance of an IP corresponding to 'DN' in the file; that behaviour is implied by your use of the `-q` option to `grep` which exits immediately on the first match.

If you want to do something with **each** occurrence, you will have to do something different.